# PHP multi elseif WP query

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Ok folks I'm at my wits end  here. I know I am close, but something isn't right. Below is code for my conditional statement, but it's not working as it should.

Essentially, on my WP site, I've got two sets of reviews, those that I did before WordPress and those after. When I moved to WP, I used a content type (Easy Content Types) which give the fields an ecpt_ preface. That leaves the others (pre-WordPress) that are using WordPress custom fields.

i.e. for the above, a "new" field would be **ecpt_trail** whereas an old one would be **Trail**

These are DVD reviews, so essentially (in plain English) it's supposed to say "If it's a WordPress (new) review with a trailer, then print out "New w/Theatrical Trailer" and if it's new without one, print "New w/o Theatrical Trailer". Otherwise it'll assume that it's an old review with the same logic.

Simply put, this works fine on the new reviews, but on the older reviews, it's not showing a trailer (and I put it on a review via a Widget that I know has one). What's wrong with the code?

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
if( get_post_meta($postid, 'ecpt_trail', true)) { ?>
<li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>  New w/ Theatrical Trailer</li>
<?php } 
 elseif(empty($ecpt_trail)) { 
?>
<li class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i>  New w/o  Theatrical Trailer</li>
<?php } 
 elseif( get_post_meta($postid, 'Trail', true)) { 
?>
<li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>   Old w/ Theatrical Trailer</li>
<?php } 
else(empty($Trail)) 
?>
<li class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i>  Old w/o Theatrical Trailer</li>
<?php  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things I've noticed.

First - A stylistic decision, but I don't think that with such simple HTML, it warrants closing and reopening PHP, and you could/should instead just `echo` out the code.

Second - Another stylistic decision, but typically the `ID` variable is more commonly defined as `$post_id`. Absolutely inconsequential, but I've changed it in my example.

Third - Do you really need to access `global $wp_query` instead of just defining the post id by using the [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) function, or even accessing the `global $post` directly? I've left that in there in case you're using it for a particular reason, but I'd consider if you need to invoke that, and just replacing the first two lines with `$post_id = get_the_ID();`

Fourth - Your final statement is an `else` statement, but you pass conditions to it. If you pass conditions it needs to be an `else if` statement, `else` statements are just to host a default value provided all other `if else` statements returned false up to that point. It needs to either be `} else {` or `} else if( empty( $Trail ) ){`

Fifth - You have weird empty open/closing PHP tags at the end of your code. You don't need those.

Sixth - Now that I've bombarded you with stuff (sorry!) I'll start addressing your problem. One part of it is that you aren't actually defining your `$ecpt_trail` and `$Trail` variables. If you want them defined you can define them inside your `if` statements like so:

```
if( $ecpt_trail = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ecpt_trail', true ) ){
    // <li>…</li>
} else if( empty( $ecpt_trail ) ){ 
    // <li>…</li>
}
```

Here's kind of what that code would look like:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;

    if( $ecpt_trail = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ecpt_trail', true ) ){
        echo '<li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>  New w/ Theatrical Trailer</li>';
    } else if( empty( $ecpt_trail ) ){ 
        echo '<li class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i>  New w/o  Theatrical Trailer</li>';
    } else if( $Trail = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'Trail', true ) ){ 
        echo '<li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>   Old w/ Theatrical Trailer</li>';
    } else if( empty( $Trail ) ){
        echo '<li class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i>  Old w/o Theatrical Trailer</li>';
    }
?>
```

With that being said, you're also probably not actually getting past the second `if` statement, which would explain why you're not seeing old trailers, considering you're basically handling the two possible outcomes of the first if statement. If the first `if` statement returns true, it stops there and outputs `New w/ Trailer`, and if not; since you don't actually define `$ecpt_trailer`; that second one returns true, and it stops there outputting `New w/o Trailer`. Those are the only two outcomes of that one condition.

Now, I also think you have a lot of redundancies in here that could be cleaned out - and you could also possibly make this easier on yourself by looping through all the old posts with the old meta key, and using [`add_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) to clone the value. Then you'd only need to worry about one meta_key, and could discard the old one.

Also, [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) will return `false` on failure, you can use that to your advantage instead of worrying if it's `empty` or not, since it will return a truthy value on success as well.

Here's how I'd consider doing it - since both failure conditions don't tell you if `no trailer` is actually a New without or an Old without:

```
<?php
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if( $trailer = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ecpt_trail', true ) ){
        // New Trailer Exists, $trailer now defined as `ecpt_trail` value
        echo '<li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>  New w/ Theatrical Trailer</li>';
    } else if( $trailer = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'Trail', true ) ){
        // New Trailer not there, $trailer now defined as `Trail` value
        echo '<li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>  Old w/ Theatrical Trailer</li>';
    } else {
        // Neither Trailer exists, $trailer now defined as `false`
        echo '<li class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i>  Either w/o Theatrical Trailer</li>';
    }
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I can't thank you enough! I also like that you provided reasoning for what you did. I think this will help me learn this stuff as opposed to arbitrarily putting chunks of code (that don't work). Thanks again!